# Ionic 4 using setInterval function trying to call a function every second but the function never called

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4.  In one of the page, I try to invoke a function to update a ion-range value every second. The code was compiled without issues, but the changeMark function never get called.

Html code :

```
 <ion-range color="light" pin="false"  min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="sliderValue">

 </ion-range>
```

Here is my TS code :

```
  export class UpdatePlayer implements OnInit {

  get_duration_interval: any;
  sliderValue : any  ;

  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

 ngOnInit() { }

 play() {
   ....

   this.get_duration_interval = setInterval(this.changeMark(), 1000);
 }

 changeMark() : any {
this.sliderValue = (this.audio.currentTime/this.maxDuration) * 100  ;
    this.currentDuration = this.fmtMSS(parseInt(this.audio.currentTime));
    console.log('playing time Value : '  + this.audio.currentTime );
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. By changing one line of code.
Here is code change and now changeMark function fired every second as expected.

```
 From : this.get_duration_interval = setInterval(this.changeMark(), 1000);


    To:  this.get_duration_interval= setInterval(()=> { this.changeMark() }, 1000);
```